# How come this not-UTF8 string fails a test, when it should pass the test?

Tags: c#, .net, xunit.net

I'm trying to test if a specific string fails a UTF8 test.

Given the following code, this passes ✅

```
[Fact]
public void GivenAnInvalidFirstName_Validate_ShouldHaveAValidationError()
{
    var notUtf8 = ""[0] + "X";
    _validator.ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor(x => x.FirstName, notUtf8);
}
```

[image: img]
[image: img]

But when I turn this into an xunit `Theory` and pass in the bad string, it's converted to something else?? which then fails the test?

```
public static TheoryData<string> BadData => new TheoryData<string>
{
    { ""[0] + "X" } // Unpaired high surrogate pair.
};

[Theory]
[MemberData(nameof(BadData))]
public void GivenAnInvalidFirstName_Validate_ShouldHaveAValidationError(string badData)
{
    _validator.ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor(x => x.FirstName, badData); // Unpaired high surrogate pair.
}
```

[image: img]
[image: img]

What is going on here? Why is my string converted to something else? Isn't a string *always* the same string?

EDIT:

A friend suggested I look at the `int` values of the two strings, to make sure it's not a weird VisualStudio issue (even though the test fails for the theory).

Here's the numbers that represent those two strings

[image]

Comment: The conversion you're seeing is the representation of an unknown character. Maybe unknown character symbol is considered UTF 8 and therefore getting accepted.

Comment: I'm unable to recreate your issue. The high surrogate is always 55357 no matter how the "badString" is passed. xunit 2.4.1, runner 2.4.5, net6 here

Comment: Interesting. I'm on `netcoreapp3.1`, for this example ... 